# C++ is using [](int i){return i;} as unordered_set hash fuction good practice?

Tags: c++, hash, unordered-set

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    auto hash = [](int i) {return i; };
    unordered_set<int, decltype(hash)> s(4000, hash);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4000; i++)
        s.emplace(i * 4027);
    cout<<s.bucket_size(0)<<endl;//4000 here ,all the keys fell into the same bucket .
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/U1Vs1P

I find out that the ideone complier use the prime 4027 (which is the first prime number after 4000 ,4000 is the unordered_set's size) as the divisor to divide the hash value ,and use the remainder to detemine which bucket the key should fall in ,which is 0 in this case .

And I ran this piece of code on visual studio 2015,just change 4027 to 4096 ,and it returns 4000 to me too .Seems like vs use the first power of 2 after 4000 as the divisor .

My problem is ,I have several unique intergers(maybe hundreds) ,they are all in the [0,4000) interval .

I want to store them in a hash table ,so that I can insert and erase these keys really fast .

And I don't want to waste memory ,I don't want to keep a 4000 long vector for just a few ints .

I tried the default unordered_set ,but it's hash function is too slow .

So I think I can use [](int i){return i;} as my hash function .As long as I know my keys will be distribute the way (my keys are likely to be quite compact,like 301,303,304,306,308 ).

But is this good practice ?I'm afraid this would cause collision issues on other compliers .

Comment: Have you benchmarked this solution? 4000 `int`s ≈ 16kB, that's hardly a lot.

Comment: @krzaq Thank you ,but I have tens of thousand of sets to take care of ,so that is a problem for me .

Comment: @krzaq It's a graph ,my unordered_sets stands for adjacency list, actully.

Comment: @porges Sometimes I need to traversal this whole unordered_set ,bitset isn't helpful in this case .

Comment: When you determined it was too slow, did you compile with optimizations?

Comment: @GManNickG Yes.

Answer (score 4):

> And I don't want to waste memory ,I don't want to keep a 4000 long vector for just a few ints .

That's what a hash table *is*. It's a memory-for-performance tradeoff. If you want a container which can provide O(1) performance for search, insertion, *and* removal, then the price is high memory costs.

The node-based `set` has lower memory costs, but O(log(n)) searching operations and lots of dynamic allocations, but relatively fast insertion and removal (ignoring the search time). The array-based `flat_set` (aka: a sorted `vector`) gives you the smallest possible memory (and very fast start-to-end iteration), but O(log(n)) search and insert/removal operations that can be excruciatingly slow for large sets.

There is no free lunch when it comes to these things.

The only way to deal with this sort of thing is to make sure that the number of buckets is sufficiently large relative to the number of elements. That will help minimize collisions.

If you know a hash table's implementation and the hash function you use, you can *always* construct a series of numbers that represents the worst-case-scenario. But hash tables are *not* optimized for worst-case; they're optimized for the average case, where most elements don't collide.

That being said, you can always have your hash function perform some arbitrary math on the numbers. Adding an arbitrary fixed constant, doing some bitshifts, or whatever else you feel works. But again, that won't stop someone from constructing the worst-case scenario. So you should only bother with such a thing if your *actual code* frequently gets collisions and you can't eliminate them without removing something important.